# Ansible install chocolatey Failed

Tags: linux, windows, automation, ansible, windows-10

I want  to use Ansible to install chocolatey into a Windows 10 VM. I use Centos8 as Master. I manage to copy files, install .exe files from master repo, but when I use the following playbook  I got an error:

```
---
- name: "Chocolatey"
  hosts: win
  tasks:
    - name: Install chocolatey
      win_chocolatey:
          name:
           - chocolatey
           - chocolatey-core.extension
          state: present
```

**ERROR**

```
TASK [Install chocolatey] *******************************************************************
fatal: [myip.adress]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to download Chocolatey                                           
script from 'https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'; Exception calling \"DownloadString\" with                                           
\"1\" argument(s): \"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relation                                          
ship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.\"", "rc": 0}
```

Also every time I connect to any internet page from my windows 10 VM is looking like this:
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: The problem is not Chocolatey, but Windows not recognizing the chocolatey.org CA as reliable. Therefore, you need to update the Trust Root Certificates before proceeding (http://woshub.com/updating-trusted-root-certificates-in-windows-10/). Once Windows rely on chocolatey.org CA, the command will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AndersonMarques. I found the solution to my problem is, was related to the internet config as follows: I used also NAT and Bridged, and finally just using bridged and also from VMware the box with Replicate physical network should be selected. This was for me the problem and maybe is not a general fix for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please, seems this error is related to broked URL from repository, please go ahead and try this one below from Ansible documentation:

```bash
 - name: Ensure Chocolatey itself is installed and use internal repo as source
  win_chocolatey:
    name: chocolatey
    source: http://someserver/chocolatey
```

Comment: The error presented is "trust relation                                          
ship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" that relates to trusting a CA. The question also mention that other URLs are facing similar problem.